# Nest JS mapping unknown Routes

Tags: nestjs

[Please review the screenshot..
why these

[Nest] 3648  - 21/05/2022, 8:14:07 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 3648  - 21/05/2022, 8:14:07 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 3648  - 21/05/2022, 8:14:07 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/:id, GET} route +1ms
[Nest] 3648  - 21/05/2022, 8:14:07 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/:id, PATCH} route +1ms
[Nest] 3648  - 21/05/2022, 8:14:07 am     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/auth/:id, DELETE} route +1ms

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppfp4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRUJ2.png)

Comment: you're problably running an old version of the code? we can't help you without the full code that reproduces that. Screenshots aren't enough

Comment: search for `'auth'` in your codebase, nestjs's scanner can't create this out of nowhere lol

Comment: nvm, I'm pretty sure that you're running an old version of `auth.controller.ts`, not the one you've shown

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.